# Why is P-Charging-Vector header removed while sending REGISTER message?

Tags: servlets, sip, telecommunication, jain-sip

I try to send REGISTER message to I-CSCF as below.  P-Charging-Vector header is added to message as you can see below logs. I checked packets sent out and this header is removed. It seems that it is removed by the code run after SipServletRequestImpl.send().
Another problem is related to orig-ioi parameter in it. It is set as orig-ioi="Type 1cscf@homedomain.com" but quotes are removed as you can see below REGISTER message.

Have you got any idea about this problem? Is it a known bug or a limitation?

Code is as below:

```
sipFactory = (SipFactory) envCtx.lookup("sip/wae-base-sipt/SipFactory");
SipApplicationSession appSession = sipFactory.createApplicationSession();
SipServletRequest req = sipFactory.createRequest(appSession, "REGISTER",   "bob@yahoo.com", "bob@yahoo.com");
String icid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
req.addHeader("P-Charging-Vector", "icid-value" + "=\"" + icid + "@47.168.150.25\";" +"orig-ioi=\"Type 1cscf@homedomain.com\"");
```

Its output:

```
Message:
DEBUG [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.message.SipServletRequestImpl] Sending the request REGISTER sip:kk1ims1.com:5060;transport=TCP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 754594ab40ed56ac1cfa652f88364594@10.15.3.11
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
From: <sip:u6003@kk1ims1.com>;tag=28124480_0efbfc5e_9721c6b0-76c7-4c86-a352-361f52731204
To: <sip:u6003@kk1ims1.com>
Max-Forwards: 70
Route: <sip:10.15.3.11:5065;lr;transport=udp;node_host=10.15.3.11;node_port=5180>
Route: <sip:27.14.2.1:5060;lr>
P-Charging-Vector: icid-value="18234_1374589491316@27.14.152.1";orig-ioi=Type 1cscf@homedomain.com
User-Agent: WAM 7.0
Expires: 600000
Contact: <sip:u6003@27.14.152.1:5060;domain=kk1ims1.com>;maddr=27.14.152.1;g.3gpp.icsi_ref="urn%3Aurn-7%3A3gpp-service.ims.icsi.mmtel";video;sip.instance="<urn:uuid:sip:u6003@kk1ims1.comsip:u6003@kk1ims1.com>"
Supported: path
Authorization: Digest username="u6003@kk1ims1.com",uri="sip:u6003@kk1ims1.com:5060",response="",integrity-protected=no
P-Visited-Network-ID: Leia
Require: path
Path: <sip:pcscf@27.14.152.1:5060;lr;net-orig>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 27.14.152.1:5060;branch=z9hG4bK9721c6b0-76c7-4c86-a352-361f52731204_0efbfc5e_649047033197297
Content-Length: 0

Packets:
10.15.3.11 (Src Port: 5180) ->  10.15.3.11 (Dst Port: ca-2 (5065)) => Header exists in packet 
27.14.152.1  (Src Port: 5060) ->  27.14.2.1 (Dst Port: ca-2 (5065))  => Header does not exist in packet
```

Create a PChargingVector header by using 1.2.167 version of jain-sip-ri.

```
String val1 = "icid-value=\"218ace3d-12e7-4eb6-87a2-0bc7a744743d@47.168.150.25\";orig-ioi=\"1cscf@homedomain.com\"";
Header header1 =  SipFactory.getInstance().createHeaderFactory().createHeader("P-Charging-Vector", val1);            
System.out.println(header1.toString());
```

Output:

P-Charging-Vector: icid-value="218ace3d-12e7-4eb6-87a2-0bc7a744743d@47.168.150.25";orig-ioi=1cscf@homedomain.com

Thanks in advance

hozlem

Comment: gov.nist.javax.sip.parser.ims.PChargingVectorParser tries to parse the name/value pairs with gov.nist.core.ParserCore.nameValue() method. You can "fix it" in both places or just skip the header parser altogether.

Comment: You mean that parse method in PChargingVectorParser class should be modified and "super.parse(chargingVector);" line can be skipped?

Do you have any idea that it is a known bug or i am the first person faced with this problem?

Thank you hozlem

Comment: Oh now I see you are trying to send the request with quotes, but then their are stripped on send and completely lost on the next hop in the load balancer. That makes sense. In that case I need to see how do you create the P-Charging-Vector header, because I have a test here where it does appear quoted normally. Please paste code.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question by adding code you requested. Main problem is P-Charging-Vector is removed from SIP Register message while sending it from SLB to I-CSCF. Stripping quotes might be caused it. Thank you

Comment: Which version of JSIP are you using? I think the latest doesn't have this issue.

Comment: I will try jain-sip-ri 1.2.167. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried 1.2.167 and result is not changed :( Then, I implemented a basic functionality to create a PCV header, its code is shown in question. As you can see above, there is not any quotes again in its output. I debug PChargingVector class and modify encodeBody() method for ORIG_IOI parameter. I called encode method of NameValue for ORIG_IOI. After this modification, output is correct. Do you have any idea? Thank you

Comment: Try a newer version from trunk. The quote on encode problem doesn't exist anymore https://java.net/projects/jsip/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/gov/nist/javax/sip/header/ims/PChargingVector.java?rev=2304 lines 65-76. The problem with parsing the header without quotes is still valid though.

Comment: I tried last version of the file and everything works good :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

JSIP doesn't like missing quotes around the second parameter. The header should be like this to pass:

```
P-Charging-Vector: icid-value="18234_1374589491316@27.14.152.1";orig-ioi="Type 1cscf@homedomain.com"
```

I am not sure if it is formally required, but JSIP requires it. I can take a look and fix it when I have some more time.

Comment: You mean that parse method in PChargingVectorParser class should be modified and "super.parse(chargingVector);" line can be skipped? Do you have any idea that it is a known bug or i am the first person faced with this problem? Thank you
hozlem